# Creating column if the value exist in lists

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am very new to python and I am trying to make a column if a values in list exists in a column.

I have series of ID's

0    A1

1    A2

2    A3

And I have a dataframe:

| ID | age |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 10 |
| A3 | 20 |
| A4 | 20 |

with the series and dataframe the output should look like below:
And I have a dataframe:

| ID | age | series_yn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 10 | 1 |
| A3 | 20 | 1 |
| A4 | 20 | 0 |

I was trying to use a code that looks like,
`df[series_yn] == 1 = df[ID].isin(series)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert boolean mask to integers:

```
df['series_yn'] = df['ID'].isin(series).astype(int)
```

Or pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['series_yn'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(series), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Did you mean to drop the `.astype(int)` for the `np.where` option? `np.where(df['ID'].isin(series), 1, 0)`